# Reset BIOS Password in a Toshiba Satellite C50D-A-10K

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop, reset

I've been looking for days to reset the BIOS password on a Toshiba C50D-A laptop. I have found information on the C50D-B but not the A model. The board model is PT10ABX. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

That model is from 2013, so less than ten years old. Machines from that vintage and newer require a knowledge of the BIOS password to change it. 20 year old tricks (drain the batteries, short a jumper) do not work any more for obvious security reasons.

You would have to contact Toshiba support, but it is doubtful they will do much for a machine long out of warranty.

If you can start the machine, use it as is. If you cannot, then you are out of luck.

I have that age of a different make and the manufacturer is very clear about keeping records.